# Prevent the footnote from being uppercased

Tags: footnotes, uppercase

I have created a new command using `\MakeUppercase`. When there is a footnote within this command, its text is also changed to uppercase. How to avoid the case change?
My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

\def\localtest#1{\noindent\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\localtest{Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening of upper layer soil to create seedbed.\protect\footnote{Footnote inside local command}}

Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening\footnote{Normal footnotes} of upper layer soil to create seedbed. The rotavator has higher soil mixing capacity compared with other plough machine and it has good weed cutting capability and it leads to the water-air, thermal and nutrient of the soil is improved. The rotavator can be easily adjusted for various working depths for soil bed preparation. The rotavator tiller is suitable for all type of soil preparation no matter about the soil type, soil conditions and Service life of the blade may vary depends upon the property of soil and moisture content in the soil. Normally the heavy loam soil consumes more energy and subjected more wear when compared to other soils. Now a day's Indian farmers are unhappy about money spent for soil bed preparation because of raise in fuel price and rotavator blade replacement cost. So the farmers focused more in reducing the land preparation cost and increase in yield. Blades are the main parts of rotavator tiller (Fig.1), which directly engaged with the soil to prepare the seed bed for cultivation land


Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening of upper layer soil to create seedbed. The rotavator has higher soil mixing capacity compared with other plough machine and it has good weed cutting capability and it leads to the water-air, thermal and nutrient of the soil is improved. The rotavator can be easily adjusted for various working depths for soil bed preparation. The rotavator tiller is suitable for all type of soil preparation no matter about the soil type, soil conditions and Service life of the blade may vary depends upon the property of soil and moisture content in the soil. Normally the heavy loam soil consumes more energy and subjected more wear when compared to other soils. Now a day's Indian farmers are unhappy about money spent for soil bed preparation because of raise in fuel price and rotavator blade replacement cost. So the farmers focused more in reducing the land preparation cost and increase in yield. Blades are the main parts of rotavator tiller (Fig.1), which directly engaged with the soil to prepare the seed bed for cultivation land

Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening of upper layer soil to create seedbed. The rotavator has higher soil mixing capacity compared with other plough machine and it has good weed cutting capability and it leads to the water-air, thermal and nutrient of the soil is improved. The rotavator can be easily adjusted for various working depths for soil bed preparation. The rotavator tiller is suitable for all type of soil preparation no matter about the soil type, soil conditions and Service life of the blade may vary depends upon the property of soil and moisture content in the soil. Normally the heavy loam soil consumes more energy and subjected more wear when compared to other soils. Now a day's Indian farmers are unhappy about money spent for soil bed preparation because of raise in fuel price and rotavator blade replacement cost. So the farmers focused more in reducing the land preparation cost and increase in yield. Blades are the main parts of rotavator tiller (Fig.1), which directly engaged with the soil to prepare the seed bed for cultivation land


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `expl3`. Instead of `\MakeUppercase`, you may consider using `\text_uppercase:n` which is more customizable. One can then locally exclude `\footnote` from being uppercased by adding it to `\l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl`.

```
\group_begin:
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \footnote }
\text_uppercase:n { #1 }
\group_end:
```

Below is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\localtest#1{
    \noindent
    \group_begin:
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \footnote }
    \text_uppercase:n { #1 }
    \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% **\def\localtest#1{\noindent\MakeUppercase{#1}}**

\localtest{Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening of upper layer soil to create seedbed.**\protect\footnote{Footnote inside local command}**}

Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening\footnote{Normal footnotes} of upper layer soil to create seedbed. The rotavator has higher soil mixing capacity compared with other plough machine and it has good weed cutting capability and it leads to the water-air, thermal and nutrient of the soil is improved. The rotavator can be easily adjusted for various working depths for soil bed preparation. The rotavator tiller is suitable for all type of soil preparation no matter about the soil type, soil conditions and Service life of the blade may vary depends upon the property of soil and moisture content in the soil. Normally the heavy loam soil consumes more energy and subjected more wear when compared to other soils. Now a day's Indian farmers are unhappy about money spent for soil bed preparation because of raise in fuel price and rotavator blade replacement cost. So the farmers focused more in reducing the land preparation cost and increase in yield. Blades are the main parts of rotavator tiller (Fig.1), which directly engaged with the soil to prepare the seed bed for cultivation land


Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening of upper layer soil to create seedbed. The rotavator has higher soil mixing capacity compared with other plough machine and it has good weed cutting capability and it leads to the water-air, thermal and nutrient of the soil is improved. The rotavator can be easily adjusted for various working depths for soil bed preparation. The rotavator tiller is suitable for all type of soil preparation no matter about the soil type, soil conditions and Service life of the blade may vary depends upon the property of soil and moisture content in the soil. Normally the heavy loam soil consumes more energy and subjected more wear when compared to other soils. Now a day's Indian farmers are unhappy about money spent for soil bed preparation because of raise in fuel price and rotavator blade replacement cost. So the farmers focused more in reducing the land preparation cost and increase in yield. Blades are the main parts of rotavator tiller (Fig.1), which directly engaged with the soil to prepare the seed bed for cultivation land

Rotavator tiller is mainly used in agriculture for loosening of upper layer soil to create seedbed. The rotavator has higher soil mixing capacity compared with other plough machine and it has good weed cutting capability and it leads to the water-air, thermal and nutrient of the soil is improved. The rotavator can be easily adjusted for various working depths for soil bed preparation. The rotavator tiller is suitable for all type of soil preparation no matter about the soil type, soil conditions and Service life of the blade may vary depends upon the property of soil and moisture content in the soil. Normally the heavy loam soil consumes more energy and subjected more wear when compared to other soils. Now a day's Indian farmers are unhappy about money spent for soil bed preparation because of raise in fuel price and rotavator blade replacement cost. So the farmers focused more in reducing the land preparation cost and increase in yield. Blades are the main parts of rotavator tiller (Fig.1), which directly engaged with the soil to prepare the seed bed for cultivation land


\end{document}
```

Comment: This will add `\footnote` to `\l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl` each time `\localtest` is used. One time in the preamble should be enough…

Comment: @cgnieder Thank you for pointing this out. I meant for locally changing but forgot to add the grouping, edited.